# How do I convert this code to JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to convert this code to jQuery from Javascript but to no avail. This code is for adding a new item to a list which I took from the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185011%28v=office.14%29.aspx) website. 
It works in javascript but I need it to run every time the page is loaded. I tried to google for why it wasn't working with javascript and found [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28534/javascript-to-display-sharepoint-list-items-on-page-load?rq=1). The guy who asked the question said it worked well with jQuery. So, I've been trying to convert this.
All help is appreciated! Thanks!! 

Note: As I'm working for a client, I'm not allowed to use third party tools like SPServices.

Edit: Code I've done till now:

```
<script language="javascript" src="/SiteAssets/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">


</script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


function createListItem() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Announcements");

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    oListItem.set_item("Title", "My New Item!");
    oListItem.set_item("Body", "Hello World!");

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert("Item created: " + oListItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert("Request failed. " + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
createListItem();
});</script>
```

Comment: _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("createListItem"); use this insteed of $(document).ready(function() { createListItem(); });

Comment: Tried. It freezes up my screen after reloading.

Comment: are you using firefox browser if so please install firebug (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) and check console tab and refresh the browser and check for error

Comment: no problem press F12 key and select console tab and check for the error

Comment: have you added sp.js to your page

Comment: if not use this code _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("loadsp");
    function loadsp() {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(createListItem, "sp.js");


    }

Comment: Ah, saw the error... it said "siteUrl not defined". Can't believe I made such a basic error. Thanks! But the page seems to have frozen. How do i come out of that? Even refreshing it doesn't help.

Comment: :) press F12 again

Comment: Didn't help. That just closes the debug window. I meant the SharePoint page being frozen. Clicking on Page or Browse doesn't help. Thanks.

Comment: Replace var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl); with this var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        currentweb = clientContext .get_web();

Comment: it will automatically takes current context

Comment: mark as correct answer so it will help to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("createListItem");` use this instead of `$(document).ready(function() { createListItem(); });`

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, I'm now getting the error: "Unable to get value of the property 'get_current': object is null or undefined" after I refresh the page. Please help.

Comment: send me the code how you are calling that method and all

Comment: I replaced _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("createListItem"); with $(document).ready(function() {    
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(createListItem,"SP.js");}); It seems to work properly now. Thanks.